# At completing vs at having completed

Tags: gerunds, perfect-constructions

Here is an example sentence from http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elation

> There's a sense of elation at having completed a race of such length.

Is the part of this sentence “at having completed a race” a gerund working as noun?

Can't I just say “There's a sense of elation at completing a race of such length”?

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is known as a [perfect participle](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.html). It indicates a completed action. So, you use it if you want to express(or emphasize) that the action is completed. And yes, you are right *"having completed.."* is a gerund clause.

You also use this pattern if you wish to emphasize that one action is before another. Some examples are [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses)

*" There's a sense of elation at completing a race of such length"* is OK, but you only tell the existence of the sense at completing the race, and you do not emphasize the accomplishment.